# Can't run a python script ('str' object is not callable)

Tags: python

I am trying to make a python program, that will help me read notifications log easily.
Here's the code:-

```
location=open("/home/pika/.cache/xfce4/notifyd/log","rt")
data=location.read()
l_data=list(data) #Contents of log file is in string now, in data variable
x=data.count('app_name')
def rm(start,stop,p_name):
    for x in range(start,stop+1):
        print(x)
        n=p_name(x)
        m=l_data.remove(n)
        print(m)        
    data=''
    data=data.join(l_data)
for i in range(0,x):    
    #Time of notification
    t_start=data.index('[')
    t_end=data.index(']')
    t=data[t_start:t_end+1]
    print(t)
    print('\n')
    rm(t_start,t_end,t)
    #Name of the application
    name_start=data.index('app_name')
    name_end=data.index('summary')
    name=data[name_start:name_end-1]
    print(name)
    print('\n')
    rm(name_start,name_end,name)
    #Heading of notification
    head_start=data.index('body')
    head_end=data.index('app_icon')
    head=data[head_start:head_end-1]
    print(head)
    print('\n')
    rm(head_start,head_end,head)
    print('-----------------------------------------------------------')
```

But, it is giving me the following error:-

```
[2020-07-23T16:24:43]


0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "New File.py", line 20, in <module>
    rm(t_start,t_end,t)
  File "New File.py", line 8, in rm
    n=p_name(x)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Any idea what's the issue?
(p.s. i am new to programming, sorry for messy code)

Comment: In your code, `p_name` is (partly) `data[t_start:t_end+1]`, that is not a function.

What do you mean by calling `p_name()` ?

Comment: it appears to me that the issue here is that you're trying to call something as a function which isn't actually a function, like @AdrienKaczmarek says. -- that is, the value of the  parameter `p_name` is a `string` and not a `function`, which is because you've passed it the values in an array `data` from `t_start` to `t_end+1`, rather than passing it a function.

Comment: just realised the issue was the brackets. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

`p_name` is a list. So you need to use square brackets:

```py
n=p_name[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

You called the function rm() with last parameter p_name as a string.

```
t=data[t_start:t_end+1] # this is a string
rm(t_start,t_end, t) # t is a string
```

Inside the function you assign `n = p_name(x)` which causes the error.

Did you mean `n = p_name[x]`?

Comment: Yeah, it solved the issue. I was scratching my head for the whole day for this. Thanks!